# Como ordenar este array php?

Tags: php, array, classificação

Tenho este array:

```
$res = array();
$res[] = array("16/08/2013", "13:32", "ROBERTO");
$res[] = array("16/08/2013", "13:16", "AMANDA");
$res[] = array("14/08/2013", "12:36", "SILMARA");
$res[] = array("14/08/2013", "", "ROBERTO");
$res[] = array("14/08/2013", "", "KATIA");
$res[] = array("13/10/2015", "16:47", "ROBERTO");
$res[] = array("14/08/2013", "", "SILMARA");
$res[] = array("14/08/2013", "", "AMANDA");
```

Preciso ordernar por data e hora,
estou usando o sort($res) mas não ordena como preciso.
O horário em branco devem vir primeiro conforme a data.

Comment: O primeiro problema é o formato de data que está usando. Data em código é desejável no formato AAAAMMDD, e DD/MM/AAAA apenas para exibição. Dá pra fazer o que você quer, mas vai ter que ficar operando strings pra consertar essas "datas" (na verdade são meras _strings_) ao ordenar. Importante dizer na pergunta se os horários faltantes ficarão em primeiro ou em último na ordenação.

Comment: Esse array é um Result de um WebService eu não consigo tratar isso lá na origem, eu teria que recriar todo o array local, que as vezes é complexo, mais de 3 níveis mesclados.

Comment: Postei a solução para o formato desejado, uma demonstração funcional e uma breve explicação de como foi rearranjada a string. Talvez tenha sido falta de capricho do pessoal do webservice (mas pode ter alguma razão legítima em raros casos, não dá pra afirmar que foi com certeza uma falha). Quaisquer dúvidas, pergunte que eu complemento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução é usar a função `usort` ou `uasort`, que usam um *callback* para usar regras específicas de ordenação:

```
usort( $res, 'compara' );
uasort( $res, 'compara' );
```

No caso acima, estamos dizendo que quem define a ordem é a função `compara`.

A diferença básica entre as duas é que `uasort` preserva os índices originais, e `usort` não.

A função cujo nome é passado no `usort` ou `uasort` é chamada sucessivamente com dois ítens do *array* original por vêz, e você deve retornar `0`, um número negativo ou um nómero positivo para o caso de empate, em ordem ou fora de ordem respectivamente.

Por sua vez, dentro da função `compara()` vamos consertar a ordem da sua "data" e concatenar com o tempo, e em seguida retornar a comparação entre as strings resultantes usando `strcmp`, que justamente retorna `0`, `+n` e `-n` conforme desejado:

```
function compara( $a1, $a2 ) {
    $ts1 = substr($a1[0],6,4).substr($a1[0],3,2).substr($a1[0],0,2).$a1[1];
    $ts2 = substr($a2[0],6,4).substr($a2[0],3,2).substr($a2[0],0,2).$a2[1];
    return strcmp($ts1, $ts2);
}
```

Veja funcionando com `uasort` no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/vHXbxc)**.
Compare com `usort`, também no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rxqEmF)**.

Só pra detalhar melhor a função acima, veja como as strings são montadas:

```
item [0]                  14/08/2013
posição                   0123456789
quantidade de caracteres  2c 2c 4c
item [1]                  12:36
item [2]                  SILMARA 


 substr($a1[0],6,4) . substr($a1[0],3,2) . substr($a1[0],0,2) . $a1[1]
 └───── ANO ──────┘   └───── MÊS ──────┘   └───── DIA ──────┘  └ HORA ┘
└────────────────────────── Item 0 ──────────────────────────┘└ Item 1 ┘

Resultado                 2013081412:36
```

Manual do PHP:

- **[usort()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php)**
- **[uasort()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uasort.php)**
- **[strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php)**
- **[substr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)**

Comment: cabuloso hein :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters normalmente a pessoa tem a tentação de converter em time mesmo, mas é muito mais eficiente com string, apesar do código não ficar a coisa mais linda do universo (se bem que ficou bem enxuto até) :)

Comment: @Bacco Patrão seu array tá ordenando errado as datas 14/16/13 !

Comment: @Bacco Tá eerado naum tá mais que certo, errado to eu...Malz ae... Mais um pro tópico making off ;)

Comment: Agora vc percebeu que o ano muda né :P

Comment: @Bacco percebi sim, sou seu aluno... Arrumei minha resposta tmb...
 "A invencibilidade repousa na defesa, a vulnerabilidade revela-se no ataque." ‪ SunTzu Me senti vulnerável..Mas já passou...;)

Comment: Além da boa resposta vou dar +1 só pelos `└ Item 1 ┘` :D

Comment: Mas acho que um `preg_match` seria melhor ai em :P

Answer (score 3):

Tô um pouco atrasado, mas pode fazer assim também: Usando `array_multisort`

```
<?php
//array
$res = array();
$res[] = array("16/08/2013", "13:32", "ROBERTO");
$res[] = array("30/01/2011", "13:16", "AMANDA");
$res[] = array("14/07/2016", "12:36", "SILMARA");
$res[] = array("14/05/2013", "", "ROBERTO");
$res[] = array("14/09/2013", "", "KATIA");
$res[] = array("13/10/2015", "16:47", "ROBERTO");
$res[] = array("14/08/2013", "", "SILMARA");
$res[] = array("14/08/2011", "", "AMANDA");

//percorre as chaves e valores
foreach ($res as $key => $row) {
$ndata[$key] = $row[0];
//Inverte a data
$ndata[$key] = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("/",$ndata[$key])));
$hora[$key] = $row[1];
}
//ordena
array_multisort($ndata, SORT_DESC, $hora, SORT_ASC,$res);

//saída
echo"<pre>";
var_dump ($res);
echo"</pre>";
?>
```

Saída

```
array(8) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "14/07/2016"
[1]=>
string(5) "12:36"
[2]=>
string(7) "SILMARA"
}
[1]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "13/10/2015"
[1]=>
string(5) "16:47"
[2]=>
string(7) "ROBERTO"
}
[2]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "14/09/2013"
[1]=>
string(0) ""
[2]=>
string(5) "KATIA"
}
[3]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "16/08/2013"
[1]=>
string(5) "13:32"
[2]=>
string(7) "ROBERTO"
}
[4]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "14/08/2013"
[1]=>
string(0) ""
[2]=>
string(7) "SILMARA"
}
[5]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "14/05/2013"
[1]=>
string(0) ""
[2]=>
string(7) "ROBERTO"
}
[6]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "14/08/2011"
[1]=>
string(0) ""
[2]=>
string(6) "AMANDA"
}
[7]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(10) "30/01/2011"
[1]=>
string(5) "13:16"
[2]=>
string(6) "AMANDA"
}
}
```

É isso ? Agora tá certim...