# função php para inverter data

Tags: php

Galera montei uma função bem simples para inverter a data, veja só:

```
function inverteData($data) {
   if(count(explode("/",$data)) > 1){
      return implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
   }
   else if(count(explode("-",$data)) > 1) {
      return implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
   }
}
```

Exemplo 1 de como ele funciona:

```
inverteData("10/02/2006");
```

Ela me retorna 2006-02-10

Exemplo 2 de como ele funciona:

```
inverteData("2006-02-10");
```

Ela me retorna 10/02/2006

Bom preciso fazer ele converter também a seguinte data: (200206) para (2006-02-20).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Voce poderia utilizar a função `date()`, tipo assim: `date("Y-m-d");`, ele pegaria a data em "10/02/2006" e ordenaria da forma certa, ja este outro formato de data, voce poderia fazer separando os numeros de 2 em 2

Comment: Acho que pode ajudar : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139787/como-ordenar-este-array-php/139797#139797

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma, seria usar o `substr`:

```
function inverteData($data) {
    if (count(explode("/", $data)) > 1) {
        return implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $data)));
    } elseif (count(explode("-", $data)) > 1) {
        return implode("/", array_reverse(explode("-", $data)));
    }else{
        return '20' . substr($data,4,2) . '-' . substr($data,2,2) . '-' . substr($data,0,2);
    }
}


echo inverteData('200206'); // retorna: 2006-02-20
```

Comment: muito bom era isso mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria com operação de **data**, não tem `if` dentro do método e ficaria livre ***dependendo das configurações***:

```
function data_format($format_ini, $value, $format_end)
{
    $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format_ini, $value);
    if ($d)
    {
        return $d->format($format_end);
    }
    return null;
}


echo data_format("d/m/Y", "10/02/2006", "Y-m-d");
echo '<br>';
echo data_format("Y-m-d", "2006-02-10", "d/m/Y");
echo '<br>';
echo data_format("dmy", "200206", "Y-m-d");
```

[***Exemplo***](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0320cdc7676fb6e274292fdcc4b6075eaca0855a)

Comment: boa implementação (+1).

Comment: Vlw @AllanAndrade

Answer (score 1):

Usando REGEX, Creio que fica tudo mais simples.

```
function reverseDate($date, $hours = true){

    $patternBR  = '~(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2,4})( (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?~';
    $patternEUA = '~(\d{2,4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})( (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?~';

    preg_match($patternBR, $date, $match);
    $isDateBR = !empty($match);

    if(!$isDateBR){
        preg_match($patternEUA, $date, $match);
    }

    if(empty($match)){
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
    }

    $formatBR = '%s/%s/%s';
    $formatEUA = '%s-%s-%s';
    $format = $isDateBR?$formatEUA:$formatBR;

    $date = sprintf($format, $match[3], $match[2], $match[1]);
    if($hours){
        if(isset($match[5])){
            $date .= sprintf(' %s:%s:%s', $match[5], $match[6], $match[7]);
        }else{
            $date .= (' '.date('h:i:s'));
        }
    }
    return $date;
}

echo reverseDate(date('Y-m-d'));    # 15/09/2016 11:20:45
echo reverseDate(date('d/m/Y'));    # 2016-09-15 11:20:45
echo reverseDate(date('y-m-d'));    # 15/09/16 11:20:45
echo reverseDate(date('d/m/y'));    # 16-09-15 11:20:45
```